# How do I create a water ripple distortion animation on text?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, adobe-after-effects

[image: Artissima 2017 by Studio Sonnoli]

Hi everyone. Can you please help me to understand the process behind it?

I'm studying the process starting from the static image so through displacement map on photoshop but I'd like to obtain my image from a random alteration made by a liquid-in-motion effect applied on my text. I'm wondering if there's a "displacement map" effect on after effect or in general what are the main steps behind this work!Thanks for you help!

Comment: Please explain what you've tried. We strive to *help* around here, not be a "tutorial on demand" site.

Comment: Never meant it! I'm a student and i'm here to learn, not to pretend anything. I would be grateful if you could help me. 
So, I'm studying the process starting from the static image so through displacement map on photoshop but I'd like to obtain my image from a random alteration made by  a liquid-in-motion effect applied on my text. I'm wondering if there's a "displacement map" effect on after effect or in general what are the main steps behind this work!

Comment: Yes there is a displacement method in after effects. But there is no reason you can not do this in ps.

Comment: You need your text as a texture, put it on a surface in 3d and wobble the surface. Maybe you need to reflect it on another surface as well. Use some "animated waving flag" tutorials for Cinema4d or blender and liquify the result.

Comment: This should probably be a comment more than an answer, since it is very broad.

Comment: Sorry, I can't comment on posts yet.

Comment: If you care to elaborate further and improve your answer I'll give you an upvote which will get you 20% of the way towards commenting **:D**